# how to find a mov (quick time format) file a video or not using asp.net(c#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, content-type

I want to find **whether an uploaded mov file is a video or not** through asp.net(c#) code. This is to **prevent uploads after changing the extension to .mov**.

Any one please help me out to solve the above issue...

Answer (score 0):

Read the first few bytes and compare them to what you know a .mov file's header is.

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1331793.aspx

Comment: Please mark answered or add a comment to get further information that will bring you to a solution, Harun.